# Select Data from Table and compare Column in The Same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this table "insurance" in SQL Server 2008

```
insuranceId    StartDate         EndDate         CarID
   1           1-jan-2010        1-Jan-2011       1
   2           2-Jan-2011        2-Jan-2012       1
   3           1-Jan-2012        1-Jan-2012       2
```

I need to write Query Return  :

cars were insurance by two consecutive

This database For Insurance Company  I need to get the Car that have  two consecutive Insurance

in the other word get the car which Enddate in the record = (startdate + 1)  in The other record for the car

for this table i need to get the carId = 1 because

`EndDate in Firstrecord = 1-Jan-2011 and the StartDate in second record = 2-Jan-2011`

Comment: Please complete your question, I cannot understand what you need.

Comment: To help all of us understand your dates, please record them in YYYY-MM-DD form - when I see them in their current form, I see MM-DD-YYYY, and you entered them in DD-MM-YYYY form.

Comment: Is it Ok Now I change to 1-jan-2011 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, this gives what you want:

```
SELECT io.CarID
FROM insurance AS io
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, io.EndDate) IN
    (SELECT ii.StartDate
     FROM insurance AS ii
     WHERE ii.CarID = io.CarID);
```

Comment: Not really, but close, I guess. You must incorporate `outer.CarID = inner.CarID` somehow. Seems like you'll need to switch to `EXISTS`.

Comment: Yup, seems to work, plus one! (I mean, well done!) I was a bit hasty in assuming you'd have to use EXISTS instead of IN. Perhaps, `DISTINCT` would make a nice final touch, though, in case there was, for instance, three insurances in three consecutive days for the same car, or some other situation that could result in identical IDs in the output. Still, can't be sure, that might be up to the OP.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM insurance WHERE insuranceId > 1 ORDER BY insuranceId
```

Where 1 is the id of the first of the cars you need.